# How to get deleted file when itemDeleted event fire in remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, file, delete, remote-event-receiver

How to get the deleted file when `itemDeleted` event fire in remote event receiver in SharePoint Online.

I have tried as follows but this does not work:

```
List photos = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
ListItem item = photos.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);
string filename = Convert.ToString(item["FileLeafRef"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ItemDeleting event instead of ItemDeleted if you want to get the file which is to be deleted. For ItemDeleted event List Item properties are not available.

[SharePointEventReceiver](https://ehikioya.com/beforeproperties-and-afterproperties-spitemeventreceiver/)

Answer (score 1):

ItemDeleted Event will trigger after the file has been deleted, if you want to get file which will be deleted, use ItemDeleting instead:

[SharePoint Remote Event Receiver – Item Deleting – Using Provider hosted App](https://abdulazizfarooqi.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/sharepoint-online-remote-event-receiver-item-deleting-using-provider-hosted-app/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get deleted item as follows.

```
  var fileurl = properties.ItemEventProperties.BeforeUrl;
    string[] nFileName = fileurl.Split('/');
    var fileName = nFileName[1];
```